# Trying to loop through multiple text files and append line 2 to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to loop through a bunch of text files and append line #2 of each file to a list.  Below is my sample code.  This looks like it should be pretty close, but nothing at all is getting appended to my list.

```
import os
directory = 'C:\\my_path\\'
i=0
list2 = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(directory + filename) as infile:
        try:
            print(filename)
            i=i+1
            print(i)
            data = infile.readlines()
            for line in data:
                if (line == 2):
                    list2.append(line)
                    infile.close()
        except:
            print(filename + ' is throwing an error')
print('DONE!!')
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line == 2` in your code tries to compare a text/string with number `2` which won't help to catch the ordinal number of the line being read.

Instead, just skip the 1st line and append the next one to the resulting list.

**Note**:

- no need to read **all** lines `infile.readlines()` if you only need the 2nd line!
- no need to `close` the file handler when using context manager `with ...`

---

```
import os

directory = 'C:\\my_path\\'
list2 = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(directory + filename) as infile:
        try:
            print(filename)
            next(infile)
            list2.append(next(infile))
        except:
            print(filename + ' is throwing an error')
print('DONE!!!')
print(list2)
```

Comment: This is very nice Roman.  How can I make it a bit more readable by throwing in line feed characters?  I thought this would do it: list2.append('\n')  After the line with: list2.append(next(infile))

Comment: @asher, `next(infile)` should already consume a line with trailing newline char/linefeed. But if there's some platform-specific issues you may append it with `list2.append(next(infile) + os.linesep)`

Comment: Yes, yes, it does come in with the '\n'.  Maybe it's called split, or something.  Rather than seeing the data printed like this...['asset1\n', 'asset2\n', 'asset3\n'] etc., I would prefer to see it like this...
['asset1'
'asset2'
'asset3']

Comment: I'd like to see everything stacked/arranged vertically so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

When writing:

```py
for line in data:
    if (line == 2):
        list2.append(line)
        infile.close()
```

The `line` variable is not the index of the line but the line itself as a string.

Also note that the second line will have an index of 1, not 2 because indexes start at 0 in Python.

You should at least change this loop to:

```py
for index, line in enumerate(data):
    if (index == 1):
        list2.append(line)
        infile.close()
```

Also, as suggested by @bruno-desthuilliers, you do not need to use the `readlines()` method which uses memory, instead you can directly iterate on your file like this:

```py
#no infile.readlines() needed
for index, line in enumerate(infile):
    if (index == 1):
        list2.append(line)
        infile.close()
```

Finally, you do not need to call `infile.close()` as you're wrapping the statement in a `with` block. The call is made for you.

Comment: Just a couple hints: 1/ zero-based indexing is not a python-specific thing, it's actually the norm, and 2/ no need to read the whole file in memory (`.readlines()`) to get the second line, you can just iterate directly over the file.

Answer (score 2):

When you test if `line == 2`, you are asking wether the line you read from `infile` is equal to `2` (which it never is). Instead, you need some counter to test if you are at line 2. Or even better, just index into it:

```py
data = infile.readlines()
list2.append(data[1])         # the line at index 1 is the second line
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
import os
directory = 'C:\\my_path\\'

secondLines = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    try:
        #Use open() because it is optimized and does not read the whole file into RAM
        with open(directory + "\\" + filename) as infile:
            for lineIndex, line in enumerate(infile):
                if lineIndex == 1:
                    secondLines.append(line)
    except:
        print(filename + ' is throwing an error')

print(secondLines)
```

Your version:

```
import os
directory = 'C:\\my_path\\'
i=0
list2 = []
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    #add "\\" to read the correct file
    with open(directory + "\\" + filename) as infile:
        try:
            print(filename)
            i=i+1
            print(i)
            data = infile.readlines()  
            #To get the second line, you have to use indexes
            for line in range(len(data)):
                #if line (index) equals 1, it is the second line (0th element is first)
                if (line == 1):
                    #If the index of the line is 1, append it to the list
                    #data[line] = take the element on index 1 from list data. Indexing starts at 0
                    list2.append(data[line])
                    infile.close()
        except:
            print(filename + ' is throwing an error')
print('DONE!!')
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant way of doing it is following, which takes care of not iterating through all the data as well as opening and closing the file automatically.

```py
# With open should take care of automatic opening and closing of file. You don't need to close it explicitly. 
 with open(directory + filename) as infile:
        try:
            print(filename)
            i=i+1
            print(i)
            skip_count = 0
            line in infile:
                 skip_count += 1
                 if skip_count == 2:
                    list2.append(line)
                    break # This will go out of loop and you don't have to iterate through all the data
        except:
            print(filename + ' is throwing an error')
```